# Ubuntu waits for keypress with purple screen

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a HP ProBook 4515s with 13.10 on it. When I boot it, it always hangs on the purple screen, before The Ubuntu logo appears. It is not stuck, but it waits until I press any key (I do mean any). Then the boot process resumes normally.

I have never seen this before. I have checked dmesg, syslog, kern.log and so on, but I can't find any traces of a prompt during boot saying "Press any key" or anything like that.

I would like to fix it because the laptop is for my mother in law, an older woman. I'd like it to work without any fuzz.

/etc/default/grub looks like this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to disable splash screen to see what happens.

To disable splash screen edit:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

or during the boot try to press left arrow

Comment: Well - I tried almost everything. As soon as I change the grub setup, it boots without any problems what so ever. (?)